# URL sanitization is causing refresh of the embedded YouTube video

Tags: javascript, angular, youtube

I have a problem with my AngularJS 2 app (I am using RC5 version of AngularJS 2). It seems that a sanitized URL is triggering change detection which then updates the `div` below despite not having any changes in my component state.

From user point of view this manifests itself as reload of the video while it is playing.

So in my component view I have:

```
<div *ngIf="isVideo(item)">
   <iframe [src]="getTrustedYouTubeUrl(item)" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>          
</div>
```

The implementation of the function above in the component code is:

```
getTrustedYouTubeUrl(linkedVideo:LinkedVideoModel) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(linkedVideo.video.url);
}
```

In debugger I see that the div gets refreshed quite often, by something triggered in AngularJS 2 framework.

The issue goes away, if I replace the HTML snippet above with a hard-coded URL:

```
<div *ngIf="isVideo(item)">
   <iframe src="<hardcoded youtube url here>" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>          
</div>
```

So I am suspecting that URL sanitization is causing it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? A working example of embedded YouTube videos that have their URL bound to a property on the component maybe?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Figured it out.

For anyone interested. The problem was the use of this function in my html

```
   [src]="getTrustedYouTubeUrl(item)"
```

The reload side effect was gone once I changed the code to calculate the safe url when the data is loaded in my service and changed the iframe binding to this

```
    <iframe [src]="item.video.safeUrl" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Note thatr I am now binding to a property.

Comment: This same issue  just popped up for me after months of using  [src]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.Url)'. I have no idea why it started (angular 4.4 and have not updated it). However, your solution solved it. Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony how did you solve it exactly? I have the same issue now, I am using Angular 2. I am also using [src]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.Url), but when I bind src to a property I get "ERROR Error: Required a safe ResourceURL, got a URL (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)" message.

Comment: @handris See my answer above.

Comment: How did you change the code where you calculate the safe url when the data is loaded? I'm not able to fix this problem :(

Answer (score 42):

I would try to use it with **[pure pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#pure-pipes)**

> Angular executes a pure pipe only when it detects a pure change to the
>   input value. A pure change is either a change to a primitive input
>   value (String, Number, Boolean, Symbol) or a changed object reference
>   (Date, Array, Function, Object).

Pipe might look like (**RC.6** - *DomSanitizer* becomes instead of *DomSanitizationService*):

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

And use it as the following:

```
<iframe [src]="url | safe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[**Plunker Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rwn5PlKZTVjp772wpbi4) (try to push button)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I already found another workaround, but this seems like an interesting idea.

Comment: Cannot GET /SafeValue%20must%20use%20[property]=binding:%20https://www.youtube.com/embed/wyVM1evRxNw%20(see%20http://g.co/ng/security

Comment: Nice solution! Plunker does not work for some reason, here is an up-to-date version [Plunker Example](http://embed.plnkr.co/NEp3dZsJ7i8pKDOoJB8C/)  (using Angular v4.2.3)

Comment: @istibekesi Thanks. I fixed plunker

Comment: Good solution i like it. Work's like a charm in angular 5. Thx

Comment: Thank you It not only it works well also, it's write approach.

Comment: Great solution, workes perfectly with Angular 10 thank you

Answer (score 14):

Combined the previous answers to get it working this way:

component.ts (only the relevant parts)

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor( 
  private sanitizer: DomSanitizer   
) {
  this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
}

ngOnInit() {
 this.getTrustedUrl('http://someUrl');
}

getTrustedUrl(url:any){ 
 this.safeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

template.html

```
<iframe      
  [src]='this.safeUrl'>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Just what i needed.... This approach the app allows the sanitizer to run only once.

Comment: This issue is resolved by my auto flashing google maps. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can keep your original solution and just use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

> ```
> <div *ngIf="isVideo(item)">
>    <iframe [src]="getTrustedYouTubeUrl(item)" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>          
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
<iframe #ytplayer  width="100%" height="235" frameborder="0" src="">
</iframe>    

@ViewChild('ytplayer', null) ytPlayer: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
  this.ytPlayer.nativeElement.src = this.act.iframe;
}
```

Reloading happens because of using sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl.
So we should not use it.
I think it is more comfortable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite late to the game but, it might help someone in the long run and with a newer Angular version, especially if using IFrame and NgFor loop.

```
  trackByPostId(post: FeedPost): string {
    return post.key as string;
  }
```

and in the template just use:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-post [ngForOf]="posts" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByPostId"></ng-template>
```

or

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts; trackBy: trackByPostId"></div>
```

This way Angular knows which items has changed and updates only those.