# Angular Video Making multiple request on events

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe

I have a problem working with videos in angular, im getting the url of the videos that i want to embed from a api so im using the `sanitazer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` function from angular to inject the url on the iframe tag, the video is displayed good no problem there, but every time i click any where, or press a key or scroll the window the browser make a request to the url asking for the video, so for example if play the video and the video start running and then i scroll or click some where else or trigger any kind of event from mouse or keyboard the video is reloaded again, i check the network tab on the browser and is making multiple request of the video in every event i trigger.

**HTML OF THE VIDEO EMBEDED**

```
<iframe width="100%" height="315" *ngIf="block.blockType === 'Clip'"
[src]="sanitazeURL(block.blockElement.url)"></iframe>
```

**Typescript**

```
  public sanitazeURL(url: string) {
    const videoUrl = `https://${url}`;
    return this.sanitazer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(videoUrl);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this question, apparently some else have the same problem. [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429293/url-sanitization-is-causing-refresh-of-the-embedded-youtube-video?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)